# Calculating percentage increase for rent prices in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, price, zillow

I am using Zillow Rent data to determine the highest rent increases over the last 10 years. I have a time-series line graph I made of the raw data by zip code (showing 6 highest price increase zip codes), but I want to show percentage increase as opposed to raw increase.

Here is my code so far:

```
home=read.csv("Zip_ZriPerSqft_AllHomes.csv")
head(home)
colnames = names(home)
namefilter=grepl("X", names(home))
colnames(namefilter)
names = !namefilter
colnames[names]
install.packages("reshape")
library("reshape")
dallas = melt(home, id.vars=colnames[names], value.name ="Month_Year")
install.packages("dplyr")
library("dplyr")
periodCutter=function(x,i) {

  strsplit(x,"\\.")[[1]][i]
}
dallas$variable=as.character(dallas$variable)
dallas$variable=gsub("X","",dallas$variable)
years=vapply(dallas$variable,periodCutter,i=1,character(1))
months=vapply(dallas$variable,periodCutter,i=2,character(1))
dallas$year = years
dallas$month = months
head(dallas)
unique(years)
unique(months)
dallas2 = dallas %>% group_by(RegionName, year) %>% summarize(price=mean(value))
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dallas2, aes(x=year, y=price, group = RegionName , color = RegionName)) +geom_line()

install.packages("gghighlight")
library(gghighlight)
gghighlight_line(dallas2, aes(year,price,color = RegionName), predicate = max(price), max_highlight =6) +theme_minimal()
gghighlight_line(dallas2, aes(year,price,color = RegionName), predicate = max(price), max_highlight =6) +theme_minimal() + facet_wrap(~RegionName)
```

[image: Here is what my graph looks like so far]

Comment: Have a look at `?lag` function, it allows you to create a new lagged variable, which you can easily get the percentage increase from. Do you need the percentage increase between months or years ? In any case you may want to convert those variables to dates (rather than strings) in order to be able to use time-series manipulation functions

Comment: @Romain thanks, giving this a go! I'm looking at percentage increase between years.